# Execute windows batch command dose not run completely

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have set of commands which I am trying to run in a " Execute windows batch command" in Jenkins. 
I am facing issues as the complete set of command do not run, but jenkins marks the build as success.

```
Command 1
Command 2  # This command takes almost 90 minutes to complete
command 3  # This never runs
```

I am trying to understand if there is a timeout associated here. What are the ways to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code or at least the bash command you execute? We need a hint why the command may take this long.

Comment: Its a custom script which runs